# Embedding private/protected google docs/sheets in iframe

Tags: google-sheets, iframe, google-docs

Is there any way a private/protected google docs/sheets be embedded in an iframe. ?

A publicly published document can be embedded.

Also a private document can be embedded but the google login page cannot be open in an iframe.
X-Frame-Options deny is being thrown in the console.

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v6j-12D0HXzsmp5zITfQ48pylIRwvhywFMfKC3cYKLo/edit?embedded%3Dtrue&followup=https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v6j-12D0HXzsmp5zITfQ48pylIRwvhywFMfKC3cYKLo/edit?embedded%3Dtrue&ltmpl=docs' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Could you describe the scenario in which a public document is embedded correctly? Then I can study your case in more detail and see how to do it with a private document.

Comment: public documents are done through embedding the published documents feature...please check here https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

By `Publish to the web` you do not share the file publicly. I mean, the link to the file will remain private (restricted) unless you change it. Also, when `Publish to the web`, there is an option to restrict access within your domain called `Restrict access to the following`.

Comment: okay...but then editing is not possible through this right ?

Comment: No, as the documentation says `If you send someone the URL of a published file, they’ll see a version they can’t edit that looks different from yours.`